# Did everyone named in the Mueller report get to read it in advance?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, law, mueller-investigation

Attorney General Bill Barr said [this](https://www.justice.gov/opa/speech/attorney-general-william-p-barr-delivers-remarks-release-report-investigation-russian) in a press conference today, in regard to the Mueller Report:

> In addition, earlier this week, the President’s personal counsel requested and were given the opportunity to read a final version of the redacted report before it was publicly released.  That request was consistent with the practice followed under the Ethics in Government Act, which **permitted individuals named in a report prepared by an Independent Counsel the opportunity to read the report before publication**.

My question is, did the Department of Justice give everyone named in the Mueller Report an opportunity to read the report?  Or did they just give President Trump’s legal team an opportunity to read the report?

Comment: Interesting use of words, Mueller was a special counsel, the independent counsel [doesn't exist anymore](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/counsel/office/history.html).